# Is there a way to update a git submodule in the tree without downloading its updates?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule with a large delta that is intended to only be cloned on the deploy target (e.g., Heroku).

The `git submodule` commands I know of all update the local tree with the tree of the submodule, including the huge delta.

Is there a porcelain command I can do to update the submodule hash to the latest commit in the main repo without actually download it?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/33514642/502399 I think

Comment: It has to be the full SHA-1

Comment: @TavianBarnes That's the one, and you were spot on about the hash. Voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: Admittedly that question/answer was hard to find without knowing that `git update-index` was likely to be part of the solution

Comment: Well, now the search surface is increased.